# Running multiple consumer on single queue

Tags: rabbitmq

I have queue of email messages and sequence of message matters for me. Suppose if the message "A" was previously unread and now its marked read, then it should be index in order otherwise if sequence will changed read message will be index as unread.So my problem is how to run multiple consumer to maintain the integrity of data. Also let me know if more clarification is required.

Answer (score 0):

Queue on a Direct Exchange with multiple consumers is best for this scenario.

Use the basicQos method with the prefetchCount = 1 setting.

This tells RabbitMQ not to give more than one message to a worker at a time. Or, in other words, don't dispatch a new message to a worker until it has processed and acknowledged the previous one. Instead, it will dispatch it to the next worker that is not still busy.

Java code:

```
channel.basicQos(1);
```

For more details:
https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-java.html